# Multithreading with C++ API

Tags: c++, openmp, boost-thread, tbb, boost-mpi

i am trying to parallel my program using OpenMP and sometimes i feels that i am reaching a dead end.

I would like to share variables in a function member that i defined (and initialized) in the class. If i understood correctly, it is not possible doing `#pragma omp parallel shared(foo)` of data members (e.g. `int`, `boost::multi_array` and `std::vector`) of a class. 
e.g.: using push_back() on a vector data member in the class.
      updating values of a `boost::multi_array`.

My question is if OpenMP is the right tools for it, or should i use boost::thread or tbb? or something else... what support C++ API

Reagrds

Comment: Just a FYI, the `shared` clause is actually redundant – any variable declared outside the parallel block that is not declared as `private` (or any of the other options) is automatically shared.

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#SHARED) states, `shared` defines that an object is placed only once in the memory. For example if your `foo` object contains a `std::vector` of some type, it **should** be perfectly ok to `push_back` items within the loop. But you should make sure, that your code is thread safe, either by atomic instructions or with mutex sections.

Comment: assuming i have an array `boost::multi_array<int,1>  foo(boost::extents[10])` and then: `#pragma omp parallel for for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) foo[i] = i;` will i need before accessing `foo` atomic or mutex as well?

Comment: Of course. This is a schoolbook example of the use of an atomic operation or the like.

Comment: i dont agree with your claim that it is clear. Maybe i havent explain my self clearly. Assuming you have an array with 10 elements. The 1st thread will work only on the first 5 elements and the 2nd thread on the last 5 elements. Do i then need mutex? since each element stand for it self...